# How to open a new activity from the adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, start-activity

It turns out the code has the following form:

```java
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
        holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("click: ", phone.getClickbutton());
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Respectively:

```java
startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
```

She doesn’t want to work here.

I give the full adapter code:

```java
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
        holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
        holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("click: ", phone.getClickbutton());
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return phones.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView nameView, companyView;
        final Button button;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            companyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.company);
            button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        }
    }
}
```

- List item

That is the actual question. How can I open a new activity from the adapter ... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't dispose passed context to your adapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Phone> phones;
private Context context;

public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Phone> phones) {
    this.context = context;
    this.phones = phones;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
// Remainder code
}
```

Then use `context` to start new activity

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Phone phone = phones.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(phone.getImage());
    holder.nameView.setText(phone.getName());
    holder.companyView.setText(phone.getCompany());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("click: ", phone.getClickbutton());
            context.startActivity(new Intent(this, Information.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What would be the problem with `View.getActivity()` inside the click listener?

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi it might produce null .

Comment: Earned, thanks! But I had to change - context.startActivity (new Intent (this, Information.class)); ... on - context.startActivity (new Intent (context, Information.class));